# Builtin Camera not found in HP Elite X2 G2 in Ubuntu 21.10

Tags: webcam, camera

I could not find my any of built in camera font or rear in Ubunu. Here is the link address of my hardware information-

https://linux-hardware.org/?probe=47d816d00f

Here is some output-

```
$ lsusb
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0003 Linux Foundation 3.0 root hub
Bus 001 Device 006: ID 8087:0a2b Intel Corp. Bluetooth wireless interface
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 138a:0092 Validity Sensors, Inc. 
Bus 001 Device 005: ID 044e:120d Alps Electric Co., Ltd Alps Touchpad
Bus 001 Device 003: ID 0424:2422 Microchip Technology, Inc. (formerly SMSC) 
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 09da:2403 A4Tech Co., Ltd. 2.4G Device
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

```
$ gst-device-monitor-1.0 Video
Probing devices...


Device found:

    name  : ipu3-imgu
    class : Video/Source
    caps  : video/x-raw(format:Interlaced), format=NV12, framerate=[ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ], width=[ 1, 32768 ], height=[ 1, 32768 ], interlace-mode=alternate
            video/x-raw, format=NV12, framerate=[ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ], width=[ 1, 32768 ], height=[ 1, 32768 ], interlace-mode={ (string)progressive, (string)interleaved }
            video/x-raw(format:Interlaced), format=NV12, framerate=[ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ], width=[ 1, 32768 ], height=[ 1, 32768 ], interlace-mode=alternate
    properties:
        udev-probed = true
        device.bus_path = pci-0000:00:05.0
        sysfs.path = /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/video4linux/video11
        device.subsystem = video4linux
        device.product.name = ipu3-imgu
        device.capabilities = :capture:
        device.api = v4l2
        device.path = /dev/video11
        v4l2.device.driver = ipu3-imgu
        v4l2.device.card = ipu3-imgu
        v4l2.device.bus_info = PCI:output
        v4l2.device.version = 331026 (0x00050d12)
        v4l2.device.capabilities = 2753564672 (0xa4201000)
        v4l2.device.device_caps = 606081024 (0x24201000)
    gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video11 ! ...


Device found:

    name  : ipu3-imgu
    class : Video/Source
    caps  : video/x-raw(format:Interlaced), format=NV12, framerate=[ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ], width=[ 1, 32768 ], height=[ 1, 32768 ], interlace-mode=alternate
            video/x-raw, format=NV12, framerate=[ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ], width=[ 1, 32768 ], height=[ 1, 32768 ], interlace-mode={ (string)progressive, (string)interleaved }
            video/x-raw(format:Interlaced), format=NV12, framerate=[ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ], width=[ 1, 32768 ], height=[ 1, 32768 ], interlace-mode=alternate
    properties:
        udev-probed = true
        device.bus_path = pci-0000:00:05.0
        sysfs.path = /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/video4linux/video12
        device.subsystem = video4linux
        device.product.name = ipu3-imgu
        device.capabilities = :capture:
        device.api = v4l2
        device.path = /dev/video12
        v4l2.device.driver = ipu3-imgu
        v4l2.device.card = ipu3-imgu
        v4l2.device.bus_info = PCI:viewfinder
        v4l2.device.version = 331026 (0x00050d12)
        v4l2.device.capabilities = 2753564672 (0xa4201000)
        v4l2.device.device_caps = 606081024 (0x24201000)
    gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video12 ! ...


Device found:

    name  : ipu3-imgu
    class : Video/Source
    caps  : video/x-raw(format:Interlaced), format=NV12, framerate=[ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ], width=[ 1, 32768 ], height=[ 1, 32768 ], interlace-mode=alternate
            video/x-raw, format=NV12, framerate=[ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ], width=[ 1, 32768 ], height=[ 1, 32768 ], interlace-mode={ (string)progressive, (string)interleaved }
            video/x-raw(format:Interlaced), format=NV12, framerate=[ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ], width=[ 1, 32768 ], height=[ 1, 32768 ], interlace-mode=alternate
    properties:
        udev-probed = true
        device.bus_path = pci-0000:00:05.0
        sysfs.path = /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/video4linux/video6
        device.subsystem = video4linux
        device.product.name = ipu3-imgu
        device.capabilities = :capture:
        device.api = v4l2
        device.path = /dev/video6
        v4l2.device.driver = ipu3-imgu
        v4l2.device.card = ipu3-imgu
        v4l2.device.bus_info = PCI:output
        v4l2.device.version = 331026 (0x00050d12)
        v4l2.device.capabilities = 2753564672 (0xa4201000)
        v4l2.device.device_caps = 606081024 (0x24201000)
    gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video6 ! ...


Device found:

    name  : ipu3-imgu
    class : Video/Source
    caps  : video/x-raw(format:Interlaced), format=NV12, framerate=[ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ], width=[ 1, 32768 ], height=[ 1, 32768 ], interlace-mode=alternate
            video/x-raw, format=NV12, framerate=[ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ], width=[ 1, 32768 ], height=[ 1, 32768 ], interlace-mode={ (string)progressive, (string)interleaved }
            video/x-raw(format:Interlaced), format=NV12, framerate=[ 0/1, 2147483647/1 ], width=[ 1, 32768 ], height=[ 1, 32768 ], interlace-mode=alternate
    properties:
        udev-probed = true
        device.bus_path = pci-0000:00:05.0
        sysfs.path = /sys/devices/pci0000:00/0000:00:05.0/video4linux/video7
        device.subsystem = video4linux
        device.product.name = ipu3-imgu
        device.capabilities = :capture:
        device.api = v4l2
        device.path = /dev/video7
        v4l2.device.driver = ipu3-imgu
        v4l2.device.card = ipu3-imgu
        v4l2.device.bus_info = PCI:viewfinder
        v4l2.device.version = 331026 (0x00050d12)
        v4l2.device.capabilities = 2753564672 (0xa4201000)
        v4l2.device.device_caps = 606081024 (0x24201000)
    gst-launch-1.0 v4l2src device=/dev/video7 ! ...



I Will be highly glad if anyone can help me.

Md Ariful Alam Nishan
Contact No. +88 01711572894
```

Answer (score 0):

Your camera device in the probe is:

```
PCI 8086:1919:103c:82ca / 04-80 Intel Corporation Xeon E3-1200 v5/E3-1500 v5/6th Gen Core Processor Imaging Unit multimedia controller ipu3_imgu
```

Looks like this device is not yet supported by Ubuntu (work in progress). But I see people solved the issue with one of the cameras on the ChromeOS fork: https://github.com/sebanc/brunch/issues/1027

Try it on your tablet instead of Ubuntu: https://github.com/sebanc/brunch

Next time check the tablet Linux-compatibility before buying. There are a lot of unsupported devices in Linux. Some of them (significant part) will never be supported.